# cp-kafka: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument exception

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am working on Kafka running on docker with Linux container o Windows server 2022. When I connect to Kafka getting below error.
[image]

Below is YML file which run successfully.
[image]

Comment: So basically error ocur when i create new topic

Comment: `KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS` is not a valid argument for the confluent containers, only the wurstmeister one. I suggest you use a different version than `latest` for stable behavior

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, I have tried without KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS still its not working, Also i have tried different stable version like 6.0.1,7.0.1. getting same error message. Can you tell me what mean by Invalid argument in kafka when try to create topic

Comment: Like I said, that variable is never used, so it's unrelated to the error anyway. The error is internal to the broker, I have no idea what it means (other than it could be a bug in the latest image version, and you should try a lower one)